# Header view not working class registering error, UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to show header on UICollectionView but class is not getting registered. Below is my code.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = nil;

    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
        identifier = @"header";
    }

    UICollectionReusableView *supplementaryView = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return supplementaryView;
}

//  Registering class in viewDidLoad

[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header"];
```

One thing to tell i have not created any other class or view controller, just registering UICollectionReusableView, same way i registered UICollectionView class, it works, don't know why it is giving same error every time.
I just wanted to display image that i put on cell so no sub classing done. Just did as

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

similarly tried for header.
The error i got every time is:

```
UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader with identifier Test Header View - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Please guide in this  i am not getting what is error, already spend two days on it. What i am missing not getting. Please guide.

Comment: @Anil Ya i got that answer.

Comment: Ok fine.. I just found this question right now:) what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731644/add-selected-cells-of-different-sections-in-different-arrays-uicollectionview) question answered by me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for a `UICollectionElementKindSection**Footer**` but you registered as a `UICollectionElementKindSection**Header**`

Comment: No that was posting mistake, i edited it, that's not the issue. It's still not working.