# Add selected cells of different sections in different arrays, UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I want to add selected cells of `UICollectionView` in arrays, section wise in different arrays, means different arrays for each section. The problem is this that number of sections are dynamic. Below is my code.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *seatV;
    int cs;

    NSString *secVal = [arrSeatSel objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *arrSplit = [secVal componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    seatV = [arrSplit objectAtIndex:1];
    cs = [seatV integerValue];

    int v;
    NSString *cnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrTot objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    v = [cnt intValue];

    NSString *sect = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section];

    if(indexPath.item < v)
    {
        if([sectionInfo count] < cs)
        {
            itemPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

            sectionInfo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]];
            [selectedItemsInfo setObject:sectionInfo forKey:sect];
            cell=[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_seat.png"]];                    
        }

        else
        {                       
            [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section] animated:YES];

            [sectionInfo removeAllObjects];
        }

        [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section] animated:YES];
    }

    NSLog(@"section array:%@", sectionInfo);
    NSLog(@"section array1:%@", sectionInfo1);
    NSLog(@"selected seats dict:%@", selectedItemsInfo);
}
```

The array `arrSeatSel` is getting the number of sections and number of seats that can be choose from each section.

```
description of arr seatsel:(
 "Family:2",
 "Gold:3"
)
```

Here sections are 2 and cells that can be selected are 2. Similarly for other sections and in all cases.

`arrTot` is getting the total number of cells in each section

```
description of arrTot(
    10,
    10
)
```

array `arrLevels` are number of sections. and array itemPaths is adding the selected cells, and here the problem is, whichever section is it is adding selected cells, but each section has it's own limit of selecting cells. Hope you got my point, if anything clear ask freely.
In short i tell you what is happening here is there is seat map for different levels level 1, 2, etc. and for each level you can select limited seats, then those selected seats for different levels are required to add in different arrays.

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: @Anupdas ya this is issue is resolved.

Comment: @Anupdas ya sure i can, please provide yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store the details. section number becomes the keys and store an array of selected items corresponding to each keys

Here is outline

```
 NSDictionary 
     Key:section0  value: array of selected items in section0
     Key:section1  value: array of selected items in section1
```

Code

```
 //Create a dictionary first 
 NSMutableDictionary *selectedItemsInfo = [NSMutableDictionary new];

// During selection
NSMutableArray *sectionInfo = [selectedItemsInfo objectForKey:indexPath.section];
if (sectionInfo == nil) {
     NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array]
    [array addObject: ] // add selected item
    [selectedItemsInfo setObject:array forKey:indexPath.section];

}
else
{
    [sectionInfo addObject: ]  // add selected item
}
```

**Edit (*Imp code from discussion*)**

```
 // Follow the below pattern
 NSMutableArray *sectionInfo = [selectedItemsInfo objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]]; 

if (sectionInfo == nil) { 
     NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array]; 
     [array addObject: indexPath]; // add selected item 
     [selectedItemsInfo setObject:array forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]]; 

  } 
  else 
  { 
      // check the count 
     if([sectionInfo count] < cs) 
     { 

      [sectionInfo addObject: indexPath]; // add selected item 
     } 
     else 
     { 
       // No need to add the item. Deselect the cell 
     } 
  }


  // To remove an item  
  sectionInfo = [selectedItemsInfo objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]];
  [sectionInfo removeObject:indexPath]
```

Comment: Anil the problem is with the itemPaths array it is adding the cells when selected, but i need different arrays for each section.

Comment: Here iam also using different arrays for each section.. each section key is corresponds to an array

Comment: ok i am working on the code, let you know after sometime, let me try.

Comment: how did you created different arrays for different sections because number of sections is not static.

Comment: No problem. NSMutableArray *sectionInfo = [selectedItemsInfo objectForKey:indexPath.section]; will return nil for invalid section. Then create an array for that sectio. Check my code

Comment: i got your point, but i think due to this line sectionInfo = [selectedItemsInfo objectForKey:indexPath.section]; array is not adding anything in it.

Comment: ya correct.. se the commended line //[sectionInfo addObject: ] add whatever you want. I wil edit my answer little bit

Comment: sectionInfo is still storing nothing what should i place for if condition if([itemPaths count] < cs).

Comment: Did you get the answer? Can u update the code with new changes?

Comment: section array:(
    "<NSIndexPath 0x149e62d0> 2 indexes [0, 19]",
    "<NSIndexPath 0x149e6230> 2 indexes [0, 18]"
)

 selected seats dict:{
    0 =     (
        "<NSIndexPath 0x149e62d0> 2 indexes [0, 19]",
        "<NSIndexPath 0x149e6230> 2 indexes [0, 18]"
    );
}

Comment: when clicked on second section item, previous items of array not cleared and it adds to further in array. suppose first section has 2 limit and third has three limit so when click on second sec array gets filled by selecting one item only.

Comment: where you are checking section? First of all you have to check the the section number then take the appropriate array then check array count

Comment: how the section can be checked as they are dynamic. Or you have the code if you can please modify it accordingly, may be i am not getting your point.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30674/discussion-between-anil-and-iphone-programmatically)

Comment: Hello Anil. i want to ask something about the programming issue. Will you be able to talk now.

Comment: No dude..iam going to leave now..lets meet tomorrow 9am-6pm:)

Comment: sure.. come to the chat room.. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30674/discussion-between-anil-and-iphone-programmatically

Comment: Hi Anil need some help in programming issue, can we talk now.

Comment: Hi Anil can we chat now, need some help.